# Битрикс: как в вызове компонента "Список новостей" вычленить первую новость?

Tags: php, битрикс, компоненты

На сайте подключен и кастомизирован компонент Битрикс "Список новостей". С кодом шаблона я разобрался и как визуально отделить первую новость от остальных понял.

А вот с настройками вызова требуется помощь. Пример вызова компонента есть здесь: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/components_2/news/news_list.php

Там один из параметров - "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "" - определяет, какое количество символов анонса новости выводится на страницу. Мне нужно, чтобы у первой новости анонс был длиннее, чем у остальных.

Понимаю, что надо ввести какую-то переменную-флаг и в зависимости от того, первая это новость или нет, менять значение и подставлять в "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "". Но не могу понять, где и как в коде вызова мне это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

тут через параметры компонента никак не сделаешь, если у первой должно быть длиннее, то ставь в параметр `PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN` эту длину, а для остальных новостей, которые должны быть короче в коде `template.php` компонента использовать стандартную функцию от Битрикса `TruncateText($str, $len)` и сделай след. (пример)

```
$len = 100; // длина анонсов новостей не равных первому
foreach($arResult['ITEMS'] as $key => $arItem) {
    if($key > 0) {
         $arItem['PREVIEW_TEXT'] = TruncateText($arItem['PREVIEW_TEXT'], $len);
    }
}
```

Comment: а Вы можете изменить Ваш ответ (упростить его) - просто написать, что есть такая прекрасная функция в Битриксе - TruncateText? :) потому что пример кода может кого-то ввести в заблуждение - у меня, скажем, в template.php первая новость от остальных отделена иначе. да и переменную $len зачем вводить? можно просто число указать вторым параметром

Comment: переменную ввел, чтобы вы поняли, что за 100 в параметре, и было удобнее прокомментировать. На данном ресурсе я стараюсь показать логику/механику решения, а не полную реализацию. В реальности, я б тоже не стал вводить переменную.